# Random black spot in mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing

What is causing this offending face to turn black when viewed from certain angles? I think its flipped the wrong way but I'm not sure how to fix it.

No manifold errors pop up when I hit ctrl + shift + alt + m. It also looks completely fine when I disable the texture.

[image]
[image]

The offending face is highlighted above

Texture [here](https://i.imgur.com/BOV7pKE.png)

Blender version Used : 2.70

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64420/discussion-on-question-by-calculatedrisk-random-black-spot-in-mesh).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is waaaay too late, but anyone finding the same problem may find:

1. Could be flipped normals.
2. I think here is actually a case of that spot not having the material on it. There are ways of adding multiple materials to meshes (some faces have different textures than others). Fix this by going into edit mode, select blank faces and add a material.